can boolean or enumerative attributes influence the association number?
can a boolean or type attribute influence the number of associations this can have? how could I make it so that if for example the boolean attribute is set to 1 it means that e3 can be associated with e1 only when years of the association class are different, while if it is 0 it means that there can be more associations towards
example of when boolean is 1
e3-1300-e1
e3-1300-e1 error
boolean is 0
e3-1300-e1
e3-1300-e1
Is this type of reasoning correct?
could a solution be to eliminate the main association and create a new one in the subclasses since they are specific for those cases?


If your intent is clarity, use a specialization that has min 1 cardinality.

I don't understand what you mean. Do I change the main association between e1 and e2? Do I create others and delete the main one?

E.g., change the Boolean into a specialization of E3 that applies only when that Boolean would have been true, and make only that specialization have an association with E1 that is mandatory.

by doing this I should remove the association that links E1 and E2 and I should create specific associations for each one. I will post a possible solution

Alternative 1: specialization
Instead of having a boolean (or an enumeration) to control E3's behavior or structure, you could instead specialize E3 into E3-b1 and E3-b2 (... E3-bn if more members in the enumeration).
These specializations would automatically inherit E3's associations, and in consequence also E2's.
For the relevant specialization,  you can then either

redefine the association and its multiplicities (either using {redefines ...} at the end, or,
use inheritance between associations, as explained in detail here. This is a very visual way to show the exceptions.

A few reasons could be against this approach for example  your UML tool doesn't support well inheritance between associations, or  your implementation language does not allow to change class at run-time an you'd need rutile flexibility.
Approach 2: contraints
A simpler approach is to keep your design and add a constraint on the association or on E3. The constraint would limit the maximum number of linked E1 instances based on some predicate involving your boolean/enumeration.
This can be done in either of the following ways:

a plaintext constraint between  {E3 instances with attrubte b true can have at most one associated E1} explaining the limitation
or a formal constraint expressed on OCL, which easily allows predicates on the sets of linked instances, as explained here (easily... for the experts of OCL - Jim ?)


can I customize an association based on its specializations? example  for e4 there can be many associations with equal year, for e3 if boolean is 1 then there can only be one association of the type
e3--1990--e1 there is no possibility that this other one always exists with boolean equal to 1 e3--1990--e1 while if Boolean was 0, the latter association could exist

@dok you can indeed customize the specialization as fits the needs. However, the specialization are structural. If you have complex constraints (e.g one or many times the same year), it might become very difficult to understand all the exceptions.
